# How Can I Reduced The Padding of My Toolbar

Tags: android-studio, margin, padding, android-toolbar

Good day, can you help me with this one?

I add icons on my toolbar, the problem is, it took too much space.

[image: ToolBar]

How can I reduced them? To look Like this one below
[image]

minTarget is - 15 to 23 present.

Here's my code:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:elevation="4dp"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:padding="0dp"

android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
app:contentInsetStart="0dp" />
```